# Create Oracle DB LINK to a database with no DB_DOMAIN

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, dblink

I'm trying to create a database link between this two DBs.

**My local DB is 11.2.0.3.**

```
SQL> select * from global_name;


GLOBAL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MYDB.DOMAINNAME


SQL> select name, value from v$parameter where name in ('db_name', 'db_domain', 'global_names');
NAME                 VALUE
-------------------- ----------------------------------------
db_domain
global_names         TRUE
db_name              mydb
```

**The remote DB is 11.2.0.2 configured as follows:**

```
SQL> select * from global_name;


GLOBAL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myremotedb

SQL> select name, value from v$parameter where name in ('db_name', 'db_domain', 'global_names');

NAME                 VALUE
-------------------- ----------
db_domain
global_names         FALSE
db_name              myremotedb
```

I want to create a DBLINK in the local database to the remote database.

I have **my tnsnames (mydb's machine) configured as follows:**

```
REMOTE-DATABASE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = 192.168.1.2)(Port = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = myremotedb)
    )
  )
```

Then, when I try to create a database link in my local database, since global_names parameter is set to true, oracle appends the local domain name to the database link name

```
SQL> create database link myremotedb@myuser connect to myuser identified by mypasswd using 'REMOTE-DATABASE';


Enlace con la base de datos creado.


SQL> select db_link from user_db_links;


DB_LINK
------------------------------
MYREMOTEDB.DOMAINNAME@MYUSER
```

and if I try to use it, **it fails**

```
SQL> select * from dual@MYREMOTEDB@MYUSER;
select * from dual@MYREMOTEDB@MYUSER
                   *
ERROR en línea 1:
ORA-02085: database link MYREMOTEDB.DOMAINNAME@MYUSER connects to MYREMOTEDB




SQL> select * from dual@MYREMOTEDB.DOMAINNAME@MYUSER;
select * from dual@MYREMOTEDB.DOMAINNAME@MYUSER
                   *
ERROR en línea 1:
ORA-02085: database link MYREMOTEDB.DOMAINNAME@MYUSER connects to MYREMOTEDB
```

How can I create this database link in this scenario?

The remote db doesn't have a db_domain. How can I force oracle to create a DBLINK with no domain name?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the content of your **sqlnet.ora** file ? 
**The domain name should be listed there :**

```
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = domain.com.xxx
```

---

In case you don't have one , create a new sqlnet.ora file using the netca tool. 
- after you create that file edit it and add the entry with you domain name!

Answer (score 0):

Excellent ... yes it is working after `global_name=FALSE`.

I am testing uploading expdp dump file from onprim to AWS RDS..

```
**** SCRIPT STARTED Session: NKIM3@LIMSDEV3(3) 4/1/2019 4:18:41 PM ****
BEGIN
DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.PUT_FILE(
source_directory_object       => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR',
source_file_name              => 'expdp_msrt_md_201904011535_file01.dmp',
destination_directory_object  => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR',
destination_file_name         => 'expdp_msrt_md_201904011535_file01.dmp', 
destination_database          => 'to_rds2' 
);
END;
==>
PL/SQL block executed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**** SCRIPT ENDED 4/1/2019 4:19:48 PM ****
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply at local db set

```
alter system set global_Names = FALSE;
```

Then your DB link works.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning regarding this answer? Even if it works, OP would like to know.